# Loop every End of Month and Adding the Column every Monthly Sales Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date

In my dataframe, I don't have the date column. I only have the sales for every month from Jan-2022 until Dec-2034. Below is the example of my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [[6661, 'Mobile Phone', 43578, 5000, 78564, 52353], [6672, 'Play Station', 4475, 2546, 5757, 2352], 
        [6631, 'Personal Computer', 35347, 36376, 164577, 94584], [6600, 'Camera', 14365, 60785, 25436, 46747], 
        [6643, 'Lamp', 324355, 143255, 696954, 97823]]
ds = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Product', 'Sales_Jan-22', 'Sales_Feb-22', 'Sales_Mac-22', 'Sales_Apr-22'])
```

[image]

Since I have more than 10 monthly sales column, I want to loop the date after each of the month sales column. Below shows the sample of result that I want:

[image]

It's easy if the column is just less than 10. However, since the monthly would be from Jan-22 until Dec-2034 (quite a lot), is there any way to perform the loop and adding the date column beside each of the sales month?

Comment: `Sales_Mac-22` is a typo?

Comment: @Corralien it's certainly a typo for `Sales_Mar-22`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a `Date` column? It will be a lot easier to filter the data afterwards to get how many of a given product was sold in a month:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime

data = [[6661, 'Mobile Phone', 43578, 5000, 78564, 52353], [6672, 'Play Station', 4475, 2546, 5757, 2352], 
        [6631, 'Personal Computer', 35347, 36376, 164577, 94584], [6600, 'Camera', 14365, 60785, 25436, 46747], 
        [6643, 'Lamp', 324355, 143255, 696954, 97823]]
ds = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Product', 'Sales_Jan-22', 'Sales_Feb-22', 'Sales_Mar-22', 'Sales_Apr-22'])

month_cols = ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('Sales')] # get all the months and years from the column names
m_y = [datetime.strptime(x[-6:], '%b-%y') for x in month_cols] # convert to datetime format

# Create a new dataframe with a 'Date' column

df = ds[['ID', 'Product']]
all_months = []

for i, d in enumerate(m_y):
    df.loc[:, 'Date'] = d
    df.loc[:, 'Sales'] = ds.loc[:, month_cols[i]]
    all_months.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(all_months).groupby(['Date', 'ID', 'Product']).sum()
final_df

ID  Product                     Date        Sales
0   6661    Mobile Phone        2022-04-01  52353
1   6672    Play Station        2022-04-01  2352
2   6631    Personal Computer   2022-04-01  94584
3   6600    Camera              2022-04-01  46747
4   6643    Lamp                2022-04-01  97823
0   6661    Mobile Phone        2022-04-01  52353
1   6672    Play Station        2022-04-01  2352
2   6631    Personal Computer   2022-04-01  94584
3   6600    Camera              2022-04-01  46747
4   6643    Lamp                2022-04-01  97823
0   6661    Mobile Phone        2022-04-01  52353
1   6672    Play Station        2022-04-01  2352
2   6631    Personal Computer   2022-04-01  94584
3   6600    Camera              2022-04-01  46747
4   6643    Lamp                2022-04-01  97823
0   6661    Mobile Phone        2022-04-01  52353
1   6672    Play Station        2022-04-01  2352
2   6631    Personal Computer   2022-04-01  94584
3   6600    Camera              2022-04-01  46747
4   6643    Lamp                2022-04-01  97823
```

Comment: my data is not easy as that. Actually, I'm working on a repayment schedule for more than 15,000 of bank customers and I need to calculate of the customer discount cash flow (DCF) for every month, then the future value. That's is the reason why I need the monthly column representing the monthly sales as the monthly repayment schedule. I unable to disclose my data format since it's P&C. Hence, that's why I'm using the sales data as it easy to present ad perhaps a common data use in learning. Anyway, thanks for your answer. It might help somewhere or in the future. Really appreciated it :)

Comment: Your column names are real or not? It's important to sort them.

Comment: @Corralien everything that I show here is the dummy data. And it's almost the same as my real data including the column names. it's maybe just my typo while creating the dummy type as Mac instead of Mar. And I don't understand how it become an issue here.

Comment: If you want column `Jan-22` to be right next to column `Sales_Jan-22`, we need to know if we can sort on column name...

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer following [@fhaney comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485759/loop-every-end-of-month-and-adding-the-column-every-monthly-sales-column-pandas/71487277#comment126351199_71486366).

If all you want is to place a new column after each sales column, you can do:

```py
def insert_col_after_sales(df, sales_col, new_col):
    cols = df.columns.to_list()
    i = df.columns.get_loc(sales_col)
    cols.insert(i + 1, new_col)
    df[new_col] = ''
    df = df.reindex(columns=cols)
    df.loc[:, new_col] = datetime.strptime(new_col, '%b-%y')
    return df

for i, d in enumerate(m_y):
    sales_col = sales[i]
    df = insert_col_after_sales(df, sales_col, d)
```

output:

| ID | Product | Sales_Jan-22 | Jan-22 | Sales_Feb-22 | Feb-22 | Sales_Mar-22 | Mar-22 | Sales_Apr-22 | Apr-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6661 | Mobile Phone | 43578 | 2022-01-01 | 5000 | 2022-02-01 | 78564 | 2022-03-01 | 52353 |
| 1 | 6672 | Play Station | 4475 | 2022-01-01 | 2546 | 2022-02-01 | 5757 | 2022-03-01 | 2352 |
| 2 | 6631 | Personal Computer | 35347 | 2022-01-01 | 36376 | 2022-02-01 | 164577 | 2022-03-01 | 94584 |
| 3 | 6600 | Camera | 14365 | 2022-01-01 | 60785 | 2022-02-01 | 25436 | 2022-03-01 | 46747 |
| 4 | 6643 | Lamp | 324355 | 2022-01-01 | 143255 | 2022-02-01 | 696954 | 2022-03-01 | 97823 |

Comment: it's really works. Thank you very much. Really appreciated you came back with different alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (works only with corrected `Mac-22` column name):

```
values = (pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(ds.columns[2:].str[-6:], format="%b-%y"))
            .dt.to_period("M").dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

result = pd.concat(
    [ds[ds.columns[:2]]] + [
        ds[[col]].assign(**{col[-6:]: value})
        for col, value in zip(ds.columns[2:], values)
    ],
    axis="columns"
)
```

Result:

```
     ID            Product  Sales_Jan-22      Jan-22  Sales_Feb-22  \
0  6661       Mobile Phone         43578  31-01-2022          5000   
1  6672       Play Station          4475  31-01-2022          2546   
2  6631  Personal Computer         35347  31-01-2022         36376   
3  6600             Camera         14365  31-01-2022         60785   
4  6643               Lamp        324355  31-01-2022        143255   

       Feb-22  Sales_Mar-22      Mar-22  Sales_Apr-22      Apr-22  
0  28-02-2022         78564  31-03-2022         52353  30-04-2022  
1  28-02-2022          5757  31-03-2022          2352  30-04-2022  
2  28-02-2022        164577  31-03-2022         94584  30-04-2022  
3  28-02-2022         25436  31-03-2022         46747  30-04-2022  
4  28-02-2022        696954  31-03-2022         97823  30-04-2022
```

Comment: yours works well too. Thank you very much